Wrong output at level2 with mergeClosestClusters method
I created a program that doesn't give me the output I'm expecting.
My output is:
0: [1.0, 2.0, 0.0]
1: [0.0, 1.0, -1.0]
2: [1.0, 3.0, 5.0]
3: [1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
4: [2.0, 2.0, 0.0]

Inserisci la profondità del dendrogramma da costruire: 5
Scegli il tipo di misura di distanza tra cluster:
1. Single link distance
2. Average link distance
La tua scelta: 1
Hai scelto: Single link distance
Distance matrix:

0.0 3.0 26.0    17.0    1.0 
0.0 0.0 41.0    30.0    6.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 27.0    
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 18.0    
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
level0:
cluster0:0
cluster1:1
cluster2:2
cluster3:3
cluster4:4

level1:
cluster0:0,4
cluster1:1
cluster2:2
cluster3:3

level2:
cluster0:2,3
cluster1:0,4
cluster2:1

level3:
cluster0:0,4,1
cluster1:2,3

level4:
cluster0:0,4,1,2,3


level0:
cluster0:<[1.0, 2.0, 0.0]>
cluster1:<[0.0, 1.0, -1.0]>
cluster2:<[1.0, 3.0, 5.0]>
cluster3:<[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]>
cluster4:<[2.0, 2.0, 0.0]>

level1:
cluster0:<[1.0, 2.0, 0.0]><[2.0, 2.0, 0.0]>
cluster1:<[0.0, 1.0, -1.0]>
cluster2:<[1.0, 3.0, 5.0]>
cluster3:<[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]>

level2:
cluster0:<[1.0, 3.0, 5.0]><[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]>
cluster1:<[1.0, 2.0, 0.0]><[2.0, 2.0, 0.0]>
cluster2:<[0.0, 1.0, -1.0]>

level3:
cluster0:<[1.0, 2.0, 0.0]><[2.0, 2.0, 0.0]><[0.0, 1.0, -1.0]>
cluster1:<[1.0, 3.0, 5.0]><[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]>

level4:
cluster0:<[1.0, 2.0, 0.0]><[2.0, 2.0, 0.0]><[0.0, 1.0, -1.0]><[1.0, 3.0, 5.0]><[1.0, 3.0, 4.0]>

While it should be:
0:[1.0,2.0,0.0]
1:[0.0,1.0,-1.0]
2:[1.0,3.0,5.0]
3:[1.0,3.0,4.0]
4:[2.0,2.0,0.0]

Single link distance
Distance matrix:

0.0 3.0 26.0    17.0    1.0 
0.0 0.0 41.0    30.0    6.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 27.0    
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 18.0    
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
level0:
cluster0:0
cluster1:1
cluster2:2
cluster3:3
cluster4:4

level1:
cluster0:0,4
cluster1:1
cluster2:2
cluster3:3

level2:
cluster0:0,4
cluster1:1
cluster2:2,3

level3:
cluster0:0,4,1
cluster1:2,3

level4:
cluster0:0,4,1,2,3


level0:
cluster0:<[1.0,2.0,0.0]>
cluster1:<[0.0,1.0,-1.0]>
cluster2:<[1.0,3.0,5.0]>
cluster3:<[1.0,3.0,4.0]>
cluster4:<[2.0,2.0,0.0]>

level1:
cluster0:<[1.0,2.0,0.0]><[2.0,2.0,0.0]>
cluster1:<[0.0,1.0,-1.0]>
cluster2:<[1.0,3.0,5.0]>
cluster3:<[1.0,3.0,4.0]>

level2:
cluster0:<[1.0,2.0,0.0]><[2.0,2.0,0.0]>
cluster1:<[0.0,1.0,-1.0]>
cluster2:<[1.0,3.0,5.0]><[1.0,3.0,4.0]>

level3:
cluster0:<[1.0,2.0,0.0]><[2.0,2.0,0.0]><[0.0,1.0,-1.0]>
cluster1:<[1.0,3.0,5.0]><[1.0,3.0,4.0]>

level4:
cluster0:<[1.0,2.0,0.0]><[2.0,2.0,0.0]><[0.0,1.0,-1.0]><[1.0,3.0,5.0]><[1.0,3.0,4.0]>

So the problem is at level2. In fact I have 2,3 0,4 1 and i want 0,4 1 2,3.
I think that the problem is in a method named mergeClosestClusters but I'm not sure.
     public ClusterSet mergeClosestClusters(ClusterDistance distance, Data data) {
         // Inizializza la distanza minima a un valore molto grande
         double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
         // Inizializza gli indici dei due cluster più vicini
         int clusterIndex1 = -1, clusterIndex2 = -1;
         // Calcola la distanza tra ogni coppia di cluster
         for (int i = 0; i < lastClusterIndex; i++) {
             for (int j = i + 1; j < lastClusterIndex; j++) {
                 // Calcola la distanza tra i due cluster correnti
                 double currentDistance = distance.distance(C[i], C[j], data);
                 // Se la distanza corrente è minore della distanza minima, aggiorna la distanza
                 // minima e gli indici dei cluster
                 if (currentDistance < minDistance) {
                     minDistance = currentDistance;
                     clusterIndex1 = i;
                     clusterIndex2 = j;
                 }
             }
         }
         // Unisci i due cluster più vicini in un unico cluster
         Cluster mergedCluster = C[clusterIndex1].mergeCluster(C[clusterIndex2]);
         // Crea un nuovo oggetto ClusterSet con un cluster in meno
         ClusterSet newClusterSet = new ClusterSet(lastClusterIndex - 1);
         // Aggiungi il cluster fuso al nuovo oggetto ClusterSet
         newClusterSet.add(mergedCluster);
         // Aggiungi tutti i cluster, tranne i due cluster più vicini, al nuovo oggetto
         // ClusterSet
         for (int i = 0; i < lastClusterIndex; i++) {
             if (i != clusterIndex1 && i != clusterIndex2) {
                 newClusterSet.add(C[i]);
             }
         }
         // Restituisci il nuovo oggetto ClusterSet
         return newClusterSet;
        }

The program is very long so I don't know if I can paste here all my code.
Please help!

I don't understand what you are trying to do: you posted actual and expected output (very good) but forgot to describe what it represents, what the code is intended to do. Assuming a lot, based on comments (I don't know Italian) : is the sequence really important - isn't (2,3), (0,4), (1) the same set as (0,4), (1), (2,3)? -- (a set does not have an order)

"The program is very long" - pasting all your code here for us to sift through it would definitely be overkill. That's a good opportunity to take a debugger and step through your program to see where it starts to go wrong - you are the one who knows what to expect at each step after all :)

if you need to maintain the order, you must change the merging of clusters (last part of posted code, starting at Cluster mergedCluster = ...) - Loop over all, as already doing but if i == Index1 do and add the merge; if i == Index2 ignore (do nothing, already merged); all others are just add to the set

( for (int i = 0; i < lastClusterIndex; i++) { if (i == clusterIndex1) { newClusterSet.add(mergedCluster); } else if (i == clusterIndex2) { /* ignore */ } else { newClusterSet.add(C[i]); } )

"The program is very long"  If this is an intermediary step to a larger problem. then you don't need to post all the code.  Just explain what the intermediary step takes in and is expected to produce.  In other words, narrow the problem down to where you expect the issue lies and then create a [mre] that produces that output.  But putting in print statements at key locations and/or using a debugger to interrogate what is happening is an essential part of writing code.
